# SPO Open List from Other List in Dialog with Filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

Working with SharePoint Online/365, I want to open a SharePoint list from another list on field click. I can get the list in a dialog with the following:

```
function openDialog(myProject) {  
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({  
    url: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/develop_apps/Lists/ProjectCommunications/AllItems.aspx",
    width: 1000,
    title: "Project Communications"  
  });  
}
```

But how can I open that list filtered? I've tried:

```
url: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/develop_apps/Lists/ProjectCommunications/AllItems.aspx#FilterField1%3DProject-FilterValue1%3D" + myProject

url: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/develop_apps/Lists/ProjectCommunications/AllItems.aspx?View={1}&FilterField1={ProjectId}&FilterValue1={1}"

url: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/develop_apps/Lists/ProjectCommunications/AllItems.aspx?ProjectId=1"
```

The first one gives me the entire list (no filtering), the second one gives me "Unable to display this webpart", and the third one gives me the entire list again.

Is there a way to open the list in a dialog with filtering applied?

Comment: Whay are you using # in first option? You need ?

Comment: Same result with /AllItems.aspx?FilterField1%3DProject-FilterValue1%3D" + myProject - all items are shown; no filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To can show a list with filter in modal dialog you should use `Query string (URL) filter` web part as the following :

- Open your list page > Add `Query string (URL) filter` , configure it with your parameter `ProjectId`
- Configure the connection between `Query string (URL) filter` and your list.
- In your modal dialog set URL as the following :

  `url:"https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/develop_apps/Lists/ProjectCommunications/AllItems.aspx?ProjectId=1"`

**[OutPut]**

[image]

Also, check my article with detail steps at [Open a Filtered List URL in a Modal Dialog in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/10/28/open-filter-list-url-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)